# What data file to use for easily importing into an iOS app with Swift?

Tags: swift, database

I'm creating an app which generates a random question from a list  (currently stored as a Numbers doc). Once that question is answered by the user, the unique question ID, the question itself and their answer is stored in core data.

When the user requests a new question one will be generated randomly from the original document and it will then be cross referenced with core data to find out if the user has previous answered that question.

I haven't included the code of my app at the moment as I'm not really looking for specific coding help. As someone who is new to the world of code I'm just looking for a nudge in the right direction for me to go and do more studying.

JSON looks like a possible, but the more I read about that the more it seems that it is about an app communicating with a website. I don't really want the questions to be accessed by just anyone, so putting them on my website might not work? Could I do it with a file local in the app? maybe a CSV?

I'm anticipating the file may become quite big as I add more questions - so I'm not sure if that changes things?

Thanks so much in advance, and apologies if this isn't quite the right way to ask questions on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm just looking for a nudge in the right direction for me to go and
>   do more studying.

There are many options to solve your problem. Each option depends on your skill, time and if the solution is even necessary for the app you want to make. In the end it's you who decides on which solution solves your problem. There are a few options:

1. creating your own backend
2. have a local file in your app
3. or use a third party service like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com).

Each option has its own benefits. Just to list a few:

**Local file:**

You could have a local file in nearly any format (XML, JSON, .plist) etc. The downside is that your app isn't dynamic - you have to manually keep adding text to this file and update your app trough the App Store for your users to see these changes. If you're going with this approach, I'd recommend using a .plist or a JSON file which is saved in your project. How to implement this correctly is beyond the scope of the question, but there are plenty tutorials out there to help you getting started.

You could put your data in a .plist file. This is nothing more than a dictionary with key-value data (same principle as JSON where each key has a value). An example:

[image: .plist]

question1 is the key, of type String, containing the value "How are you today". It's easy to read from this .plist since it's the same principle as JSON.

Also, JSON is just a format, it's used often to communicate with websites, but it's not limited to sites only.

**Custom backend**

This means that you make a backend on which your app can communicate with. You'd have to host your backend, write logic / code on your backend and so on. This can be very time consuming, especially if your app isn't that big/demanding. I wouldn't recommend this unless you have the experience, time, patience and need for this solution.

**Third party**

This can be a nice solution. Using a third party service like Firebase means that you have your data online. The Firebase library has been well tested and has great documentation to get you started. It's secure, fast, simple but .. it does take a little bit of time to learn how it works - but the end result is that you have a dynamic app where you can add, delete, edit questions and so on. This data can be protected if you wish - which means only authenticated users can access this data (Nobody else will be spying on your data :))

> I don't really want the questions to be accessed by just anyone, so
>   putting them on my website might not work?

Read **custom backend** and **Third Party**.

> Could I do it with a file local in the app?

Yes. Read **Local file**.

> maybe a CSV?

That's possible but I wouldn't recommend it, but that's a personal opinion. I find it outdated and it's more difficult to work with than JSON.

> I'm anticipating the file may become quite big as I add more questions
>   - so I'm not sure if that changes things?

What is a big file? Nowadays reading a "big" JSON file is probably nothing more than a few MB at most. Your phone reads this in no time. This won't be an issue for your phone or app.

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much. I'm spending 2 full days a week teaching myself (plus evenings and weekend when I can) so plenty of time to really get stuck in - I just needed a bit of direction and you've given me that. Thanks again x

Comment: @FionaKate No problem! If you ever stumble upon a problem feel free to contact me

Comment: I recommend the .plist file, for starters. @FionaKate Keep it up, and have fun!

Comment: Thank you, this place is so helpful :) x

Comment: @hapeki Hi. I am hitting a bit of a brick wall with trying to write to a plist. You suggested getting in touch directly if I had more questions but I don't seem to be able to find a way to do that... so I've done it on here. And that is probably not what I'm supposed to do. Is there a way of DMing you or something? x

Comment: Hey @FionaKate np, do you use Slack for IM?

Comment: @Hapeki I can do, I've got the app but I've not really used it. I was member of a slack team, but I've since left it. Let me know how to find you and I'll get on it :)

Comment: The Slack channel is .... programmingdorks.slack.com, if you can't request membership you could leave your email here and i'll add you myself

Comment: @FionaKate idk if you got my message since I didn't tag my bad

Comment: Inv sent, you can delete your comment with your email if you want :) @FionaKate